# How can I stop jButton action?

Tags: java, if-statement, jbutton

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
//codes for initializing & calculating value of a  
if(a==1){
//if this condition is true jButton action will Continue 
//jButton action code ......}
else{
//if this condition is false jButton action will stop.
```

if a value is not equal to 1 , I just want to stop the action of jButton1. I don't want to stop the whole code & rerun action of jButton1. while a is getting 1. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void JButton1ActionPerformed( java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt )
{
    if( count == 1 )
       PerformAction()

    else return; //line is optional
}
```

Simply put all the ActionPerformed code under an if statement and return out (not necessary) to not perform it.